# What is the maximum number of balls in a box?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box contains balls of various colors (at least 7). If five balls are drawn, then among them there will definitely be two balls of the same color. And if seven balls are drawn, there will definitely be two balls of different colors. What is the maximum number of balls in the box? And what is the minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first statement, we know that there can be no more than four colors, otherwise we could draw five balls of different colors. From the second statement, we know that there are no more than six balls of each color, otherwise we could draw seven balls of the same color.

Therefore, the maximum number of balls is $6\cdot{4}$, which is $\boxed{24}$.

The minimum is $7$, as the problem states that there are at least seven balls in the box, and the criteria it gives us imposes no lower bounds.

Hopefully this helps!